# "The API you are requesting could not be found" error with fitbit-node package

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I am using the FitBit API for my senior project and I keep getting the "The API you are requesting could not be found." error. I am using the fitbit-node package, and here is the section causing the error:

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res) {

    if (req.session.authorized) {
        client.get('/1/user/-/activities/date/today.json', req.session.access_token).then(function(results) {
            res.json(results[0]);
        });
    } else {
        res.status(403);
        res.json({
            errors: [{
                message: 'not authorized'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

I am trying to access the /1/user/-/activities/date/today.json endpoint, but keep getting the error. I cannot access any other endpoint except /profile.json. The req.session.access_token is the stored access token from authentication. I am using the same set-up for /profile.json.

I'm following examples from this repo and cannot figure out why it is not working: https://github.com/lukasolson/fitbit-node/blob/master/example.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `/1/user/-` in the path. It is already in the client.

```
   router.get('/test', function(req, res) {

    if (req.session.authorized) {
        client.get('/activities/date/today.json', req.session.access_token).then(function(results) {
            res.json(results[0]);
        });
    } else {
        res.status(403);
        res.json({
            errors: [{
                message: 'not authorized'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: hello, I was getting the same error as you, and following your answer now the error is gone but the result comes back as `undefined`, do you know why? thanks